# Can't figure out why this Arduino code will not work?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am creating a code for a wheel speed sensor as part of a bigger group project.  The code will measure and display ground speed and distance travelled for an autonomous land yacht using a Hall effect sensor and a magnet attached to the wheel.  I have written the code and on its own it works perfectly fine.  However when I try to add it to the full project code it does not seem to work at all.  The only difference is that inside `void loop()` there is a bunch of other things happening.  I have checked and double checked all the pins and all of the code and I simply can not work it out.  it will work sometimes for one spin of the wheel then it seems to sort of exit a loop somehow as the speed then always reads `0m/s` once the wheel has stopped and started again,

Here is the code on its own:

```
int sensorPin1 = 2; // hall effect
float revs;
float rpm;
volatile byte rpmcount;

long fin_time;
long current_time;
long stop_time;
float distance;
const float circumference = 0.31416;
float groundspeed;
const float Pi = 3.14159;

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 13);


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(sensorPin1, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, RPM, RISING);  
}

void RPM()
{
  rpmcount++;
  revs++;
} 

void loop() 
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("GS=");
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
  lcd.print(groundspeed,1);
  lcd.print("m/s");
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print("D=");
  lcd.print(distance,0);
  lcd.print("m");

  if(rpmcount == 1)
  {
    current_time = time - fin_time;
    rpm = ((60000)/current_time);
    groundspeed = ((rpm * circumference) / 60);
    distance = revs*circumference;
    rpmcount = 0;
    fin_time = millis();
  }

  stop_time = millis() - fin_time;
  if(stop_time >= 2000)
  {
    rpm = 0;
    groundspeed = 0;
    delay(20);
  }
}
```

the code within the main project takes up the exact same structure, the only difference is that `void setup()` and `void loop()` have a bunch of other things in side them for all of the other sensors on the vessel.  I have checked the code over and the main arithmetic inside my code is not contained within any other `if` loops or anything other than `if (rpmcount == 1)`.

Does anybody have an ideas?

I could upload the full project code but it is hundreds of lines and this question is long enough already.

Comment: Is it possible there's a conditional return within the other code inside the main project's loop?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  There are no returns within the main project code.  Just computing data and displaying it to an LCD all within one main loop. @isick

Comment: What happens when `rpmcount` is greater than 1? Maybe you could try `if (rpmcount > 0 ) ...`

Comment: rpmcount is reset to 0 in the 'If (rpmcount == 0)' instructions so it really never reaches above 1.

Comment: @c_user Can you guarantee that `RPM()` is called only once for each call to `loop()` function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Arduino expert, but it seems to me that it would be possible (in fact, likely) for `rpmcount` to be sometimes greater than 1 when `loop()` is executed. The variable `rpmcount` is being incremented by means of an interrupt, and there doesn't appear to be any way of ensuring that loop is called once for each interrupt. In other words, what happens if there are multiple revolutions of the wheel in between calls to `loop()`?

This would be especially likely to cause the problem you are seeing if `loop()` in your full project has a lot of other tasks to perform and may explain why it sometimes works right at the start.

You should be able to fix the issue by just testing for `rpmcount >= 1`

Comment: Thank you for the response, it would make good sense as there is stacks of code contained within void loop (), rpmcount is reset to 0 in the 'If (rpmcount == 0)' instructions so it really never reaches above 1.

Comment: Sorry I meant 'if(rpmcount == 1)'

Comment: @c_user I think it could reach above one because the function that handles incrementing the rpmcount interrupts. So if your spinning wheel completes two rotations before the main loop completes (possible depending on how much other stuff is in loop) then it could get to 2. Might as well change it to `> 0` and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Other people have recommended that the if statement rpmcount == 1 be updated to rpmcount >= 1. I agree with them and here is why:

When the LCD code is added to your project it makes the loop() call take far longer than when it is not there. Since the loop call is taking so long the wheel is going to get around several times before the rpmcount = 0 code even gets a chance to run. Try removing the rpm code and putting millis() calls around the LCD code to see how long it takes to update the LCD. Then as a test replace the LCD update code with a delay of the measured interval.

```
  unsigned long temp = millis();

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("GS=");
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
  lcd.print(groundspeed,1);
  lcd.print("m/s");
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print("D=");
  lcd.print(distance,0);
  lcd.print("m");

  Serial.println(millis()-temp); // println can take a while too, 
                                 // so don't add to many in parts 
                                 // of the code that are timing critical.
```

A couple of other points to note:

rpmcount is read before a value has been assigned to it. So it should be initialized to 0 in the setup function.

The same is true for fin_time, as good practice the code should initialize all of the global variables.

Uninitialized variables might cause of some of the undesired behavior... Sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Could you possibly give some example of the millis() calls for the LCD, im not quite sure how I would do that. @Derek

Comment: The block of code in the response above is an example of how to figure out how long a section of code takes to run. The current millis is saved in temp, the code that is under analysis is allowed to run, and then the difference in time from the start is output over the serial connection. In order to see the value being produced one needs to open the terminal (Serial Monitor) in the arduino IDE.